# How to remove multiple elements in Vector in Java?

Tags: java, file, vector

I read from .txt file all of the ids and insert these ids into Vector.

```
            String pathSelectedfile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            File selectedFile = new File(pathSelectedfile);
            Scanner readFile = new Scanner(selectedFile);

            Vector ids=new Vector();
            while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
                String id= readFile.nextLine();
                ids.addElement(id);
            }
```

then I want to remove multiple ids in Vector.i can do that by for loop
but information is too big.tnx a lot

Comment: is my way wrong to read data from text file?i just want to learn how to remove multiple elements from Vector

Comment: If readFile is a Scanner instance it's correct... Although you should be aware that vector is deprecated.

Comment: @SerxanResullu Now this make sense, However please give some input data, expected result. So that you will get appropriate help.

Comment: @SerxanResullu I apologize for being rude. I don't know what I was thinking. If your problem not get solved then let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove multiple values

```
    Vector vector = new Vector();
    vector.add("value1");
    vector.add("value2");
    vector.add("value3");
    vector.add("value4");
    System.out.println("Size : "+vector.size());
    // to remove single value
    vector.remove("value1");
    System.out.println("Size : "+vector.size());
    Vector itemsToRemove = new Vector();
    itemsToRemove.add("value3");
    itemsToRemove.add("value4");
    //remove multiple values
    vector.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
    System.out.println("Size : "+vector.size());

    //to remove all elements
    vector.removeAllElements();
    // or
    vector.clear();
```

But instead of using `Vector` consider to use `ArrayList` since Vector is obsolete collection.
Read this : [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Also use generics Like `ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList()` if you store only String elements in list.

If you want to skip duplicates when adding elements in `Vector`, use the following code

```
   Vector vector = new Vector() {
        @Override
        public synchronized boolean add(Object e) {
            if(!contains(e)){
                return super.add(e);
            }
            System.out.println("Element " + e +" is duplicate");
            return false ;
        }
    };
```

But if you want to add only unique elements, use `Set`

Comment: and how can i find that an element is multiple in this file or not?

Comment: what do u mean by multiple ? you mean duplicate ?

Answer (score 2):

Do completely remove the duplicated ids, you could use the following:

```
        Set<String> ids=new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        Set<String> duplicates=new HashSet<String>();
        while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String id= readFile.nextLine();
            if(!ids.add(id)) {
                duplicates.add(id);
            }
        }
        ids.removeAll(duplicates)
```

Note that unlike Vector, LinkedHashSet is not synchronized. In most cases this is not a bad thing, but in the case that you actually need it to be synchronized, wrap it using Collections.synchronizedSet()

Comment: by this way i can get one of the dublicate elements.but i want to get none of the elements which are dublicated

Comment: first i have to find that the element is dublicated or not then remove all of the dublicated elements

Answer (score 0):

READ the javadoc and pay attention to methods starting with `remove` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html. This should be you first approach not SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you "want to remove multiple ids in Vector" do the following

```
ids = new Vector(new HashSet(ids))
```